# How to use VBOs efficiently

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to work myself into OpenGl, so i was reading a few tutorials/texts about the efficient use of vertex buffer objects. At first i thought the easiest way to render stuff is with one VBO per object, but i seems, that it's way more efficient to use only a single large VBO (at least for the static objects).

OpenGL wiki:

> ... it is better to put many objects into one VBO and attempt to reduce the number of calls you make to glBindBuffer and glVertexPointer and other GL functions

So i basically have one giant VBO and one IBO, and add my data using `glBufferSubData`. For each object or whatever i store vertex and index offset somewhere, and if i want to draw a specific one i use `glDrawElementsBaseVertex`.

My problem is, that I'm not sure what to do if i want to remove data. I could just keep it there, but that doesn't seem right.

Or i could call `glBufferData`​ with a null pointer and then reload all the other objects.

The third thing i can imagine is to implement some kind of memory management, that keeps track of "holes" inside the VBO and refill them with new objects.

Are there better ways to deal with this? It probably depends on the case. I was thinking about something like a big game world, where everything is static, but when you move in one direction, you no longer need data from the opposite.

Comment: You can make it event better, use the same buffer for `VBO` _and_ `IBO`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would use VBOs for everything: static and dynamic. Just use the right hints (`GL_STATIC_DRAW` or `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`).

Secondly, instead of using one giant VBO (which you are probably doing to save state changes) I would suggest that you use on VBO per mesh, but implement some sort of batching of meshes before you render to reduce state changes. That would do away with having to worry about any holes in the data.